# Top halves and bottom halves concept clarification

Tags: linux, interrupt-handling, top-halves

As per the guide lines of Top halves and Bottom halves, When any interrupt comes it is handled by two halves. The so-called top half is the routine that actually responds to the interrupt—the one you register with request_irq. The bottom half is a routine that is scheduled by the top half to be executed later, at a safer time. The big difference between the top-half handler and the bottom half is that all interrupts are enabled during execution of the bottom half—that's why it runs at a safer time. In the typical scenario, the top half saves device data to a device-specific buffer, schedules its bottom half, and exits: this operation is very fast. The bottom half then performs whatever other work is required, such as awakening processes, starting up another I/O operation, and so on. This setup permits the top half to service a new interrupt while the bottom half is still working.

But is if the interrupt is handled in safer time by bottom halves then logically when interrupt comes it has to wait until bottom halve finds some safer time to execute interrupt that will limit the system and will have to wait until the interrupt handled, for example : if I am working on project to give LED blink indication when temperature goes high above specific limit in that case if interrupt handling is done when some safe time available(according to bottom halves concept) then blink operation will be delayed....Please clarify my doubt how all the interrupts are handled????

Comment: This seems to a perfect question for a classroom/ training session, not much for for SO.

Comment: Sorry removed the "C" tag from my question @Gerhardh

Answer (score 6):

When top-half/bottom-half interrupt architecture is used, there is commonly a high-priority interrupt handling thread.

This interrupt handling thread has a higher priority than other threads in the system (some vendor SDKs specify an "Interrupt" priority level for this purpose). There is often a queue, and the thread sleeps when there is no work in the queue. This thread/queue is designed so that work can be safely added from an interrupt context.

When a top-half handler is called, it will handle the hardware operations and then add the bottom-half handler(s) to the interrupt queue. The top-half handler returns and interrupt context is exited. The OS will then check for threads that run next. Because the interrupt thread has work available, and because it is the highest priority, it will run next. This minimizes the latency that you are worried about.

There will naturally be some latency jitter, because there may be other interrupts in the queue that fired ahead of the LED (in your example). There are different solutions to this, depending on the application and real-time requirements. One is to have a sorted queue based on an interrupt priority level. This incurs additional cost when enqueueing operations, but it also ensures your interrupts will be handled by priority. The other option, for critical latencies, is to do all the work in the top-half interrupt handler.

It's important to keep in mind the purposes of such an architecture:

1. Minimize the time spent in interrupt context, because other interrupts are (likely) disabled while you are processing your current interrupt and you are increasing the latency for handling them
2. Prevent users from calling functions which are not safe to invoke from an interrupt context

We still want our bottom-half handlers to be run as soon as possible to reduce latency, so when you say "wait for a safer time", this means "outside of the interrupt context".

Answer (score 5):

Interrupt: An interrupt is an event that alter the sequence of instruction executed by a processor in corresponding to electrical signal generated by HW circuit both inside & outside CPU.

When any interrupt is generated it is handled by two halves.

1) Top Halves

2) Bottom Halves

Top Halves: Top halves executes as soon as CPU receives the interrupt. In the Top Halves Context Interrupt and Scheduler are disabled. This part of the code only contain Critical Code. Execution Time of this code should be as short as possible because at this time Interrupt are disabled, we don't want to miss out other interrupt by generated by the devices.

Bottom Halves: The Job of the Bottom half is used to run left over (deferred) work by the top halves. When this piece of code is being Executed interrupt is Enabled and Scheduler is Disabled. Bottom Halves are scheduled by Softirqs & Tasklets to run deferred work

**Note:** The top halves code should be as short as possible or deterministic time and should not contain any blocking calls as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you blink operation is too important to be delayed, you could put it into top half and may not have bottom half at all. However, depends on what you do in top half, it may or may not affect system performance.

I would suggest you write code for both cases and perform some profilings